# Number of concurrent database connections

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

We are using amazon r3.8xlarge postgres RDS for our production server.I checked the max connections limit of the RDS, it happens to be 8192 max connections limit.
I have a service which is deployed in ECS and each ECS tasks can take one database connection.The tasks go up to 2000 during peak load.That means we will have 2000 concurrent connections to the database.

I want to check whether it is ok to have 2000 concurrent connections to database.secondly, Will it impact the performance of amazon postgres RDS.

Comment: 8192 will be number of connections at a given time. How many connections do each container concurrently make? one?

Comment: yes.Each container is making one database connection.so we have 1000 tasks running container across instances.Other than that 500 -1000 connections are from other services.

Comment: The key question is how many of these connections are active at the same time. That shouldn't be more than you have cores. Can you use a connection pooler?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is on the money here. You should ignore the fact that RDS is hosting your database and read up on postgres scaling - virtually everything that applies generally also applies to an RDS hosted instance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having 2000 connection at time should not cause any performance issue, since AWS manages the performance part. There are many DB load testing tools available, if you want to be at most sure about this.

Comment: AWS does not "manage the performance part". They do provide high performance hardware and networking, but that's essentially it. If you're using RDS and hoping that AWS will magically make it scale where a non-RDS instance would falter, I think you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Also, many database connections cause a performance issue, because the snapshot that is taken at the beginning of every query becomes more expensive. This has been ameliorated in v14, but is still the case. The solution is to use way fewer connections and a connection pool.